# What it is the second sign below "Yah" on Psalm 68:5?

Tags: hebrew, psalms

On Psalm 68:5 "Yah" have a second sign below (it is like a ','), it is a vowel too? Or what it is and what is it function?

Answer (score 1):

**Merkha מֵרְכָ֥א** trope in Psalm 98:5, יָ֥הּ "Yah" serves readers cantillation of the Yod (when singing HaShem). | In the  key E (under middle C), "Yah" יָ֥הּ (with merkha) is sung for one half note.